# <noscript> tag displays hidden form

Tags: html

Can someone just confirm that this is something thats wrong with my browser specifically I've got a noscript tag:

```
<noscript><input type="hidden" name="javascript" value="no_javascript"></noscript>
```

When javascript is off I get this showing in my browser

```
<input type="hidden" name="javascript" value="no_javascript">
```

Crazy stuff eh?

Comment: So it shows the actual text in the browser?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does but I think it still works as well when I use it in a post.

Answer (score 0):

that is normal... `<noscript>` only shows what is between the tag if javascript is off or more commonly not supported to display things like this

`<noscript>`Your browser does not support javascript please get a better one...`</noscript>`

Comment: But it should be parsing the HTML inside of it.

Comment: Just in case your interested I just made quite a serious mistake with my programming?  The fact is I couldn't see any of my code because I had a function in another file. Scary Stuff hey guys!